# What algorithms can be used to build predictors from fractions of time series?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction

Let S and T be sets of time series labelled with a property. Each time series is highly periodic and in fact contains subsequent repeats of the same process (consider e.g. a gait recording, which is a time series of foot positions that repeat the same motion, which I'm calling a segment for simplicity's sake).

What is a good feature extractor if my objective is to build a model that from a sequence of such segments returns a similarity score to S or T? Ignore the model itself for now - just consider feature extraction for the time being,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described falls into below problem:

- Given a sequence features.
- Classify or recognize the hidden state.

For example, in machine-vision, the sequence could be images captured continuously against a moving human. The goal is to identify certain categories of gestures.

In your problem, the input is d-dimensional time series data and your output is the probability of two classes (`S` and `T`).

There are some general methods to handle such problem, namely, hidden markov model ([HMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model)) and conditional random fields ([CRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field)).